# How to set the Position of a MediaElement upon button click?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, mediaelement

I'm working on a Xamarin Forms application. Right now I'm trying to implement custom video controls into my MediaElement but I'm failing to do so, and googling isn't helping much.

Basic overview, I have a MediaElement playing a video, and I have two buttons on each side of the video that I would like the user to be able to press and rewind or fast forward 5 seconds. The buttons recognize being clicked, but do not do what I want them to, and I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. Here is my code:

```html
Page.xaml
...
<Grid BackgroundColor="#E5EBEE">

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <MediaElement x:Name="LessonVideo"
                      Source="ms-appx:///vid_IntroDemo.mp4" 
                      ShowsPlaybackControls="False"
                      IsLooping="True" 
                      Aspect="AspectFill" 
                      AutoPlay="True" 
                      KeepScreenOn="True"
                      HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                      VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                      Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                      />
        <BoxView Opacity="0.0" BackgroundColor="#00C2FF"/>
        <Button x:Name="Back" BackgroundColor="Yellow" Grid.Column="0" Opacity="0.2" Clicked="RewindVideo"></Button>
        <Button x:Name="Forward" BackgroundColor="Red" Grid.Column="2" Opacity="0.2"></Button>
    </Grid>
```

```html
Page.xaml.cs
...
private void RewindVideo(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (LessonVideo.CanSeek) 
            {
                LessonVideo.Position = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(LessonVideo.Position.TotalSeconds - 5);
            }
            
        }
```

I've experimented with stopping and playing the video, but nothing seems to be working. Help me out and point me in the right direction how to solve this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: is `CanSeek` true?  Have you checked the values you're calculating for `Position` to be sure they're correct?

Comment: @Jason it appears so. It does pass the if condition, and the TimeSpan is calculated by subtracting 5 from the video. The MediaElement, however, does not change

Comment: @AndrewtheProgrammer Hi, there is a `CanSeek` preoperty of `MediaElement`, you could check whehter it be true for setting a custom position. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/views/mediaelement

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT he is already doing exactly that in his code

Comment: @Jason Oh, if that does work. Maybe it need to use custom renderer to get the VideoPlayer in native, then can control its position.

Answer (score 0):

With the [.NET MAUI Community Toolkit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/views/mediaelement), I have been able to achieve playback position control using the `SeekTo()` method:

```
MyMediaElement.SeekTo(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(newPositionInSeconds));
```

I personally implemented a *Slider* control to do this, and I had to put on pause the music before to call to `SeekTo()`

If you are interested to see it in action, I have written a series of articles about the MediaElement. You can start from [here](https://www.mauicestclair.fr/en/posts/tutos/my-first-app/11-control-playback-position-with-mediaelement).